# selinux preventing init_t access to httpd_sys_content_t

Tags: linux, security, webserver, selinux

I have a systemd service file that runs a script. It is getting blocked by selinux:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1570329687.437:218): avc:  denied  { execute } for  pid=1079 comm="(index.sh)" name="make_index.sh" dev="md127" ino=4295130138 scontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1

type=AVC msg=audit(1570329687.437:219): avc:  denied  { read open } for  pid=1079 comm="(index.sh)" path="/srv/www/sites/linux.montclaire.lan/make_index.sh" dev="md127" ino=4295130138 scontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1

type=AVC msg=audit(1570329687.437:220): avc:  denied  { execute_no_trans } for  pid=1079 comm="(index.sh)" path="/srv/www/sites/linux.montclaire.lan/make_index.sh" dev="md127" ino=4295130138 scontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1

type=AVC msg=audit(1570329687.450:221): avc:  denied  { ioctl } for  pid=1079 comm="make_index.sh" path="/srv/www/sites/linux.montclaire.lan/make_index.sh" dev="md127" ino=4295130138 ioctlcmd=0x5401 scontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1

type=AVC msg=audit(1570329691.303:222): avc:  denied  { create } for  pid=1081 comm="make_index.sh" name="index.html" scontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1

type=AVC msg=audit(1570329691.322:223): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=1081 comm="make_index.sh" name="index.html" dev="md127" ino=4295112722 scontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1

type=AVC msg=audit(1570329691.322:224): avc:  denied  { open } for  pid=1081 comm="make_index.sh" path="/srv/www/sites/linux.montclaire.lan/index.html" dev="md127" ino=4295112722 scontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1

type=AVC msg=audit(1570329691.322:225): avc:  denied  { append } for  pid=1081 comm="make_index.sh" name="index.html" dev="md127" ino=4295112722 scontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
```

So I created a selinux  module:

```
module montclaire 1.0;

require {

    type httpd_sys_content_t;
    type init_t;
    class file { append create execute execute_no_trans ioctl open read write };
}

#============= init_t ==============
allow init_t httpd_sys_content_t:file { append create execute execute_no_trans ioctl open read write };
```

compiled and loaded it. My script is running with selinux enforcing.

Is this the correct thing to do? Did I put a big hole in my system?

My systemd service file: I run on as a timer not on boot.

```
[Unit]
Description=Sync montclaire repositories
ConditionPathExists=/srv/www/sites/linux.montclaire.lan/make_index.sh

[Service]
User=nginx
Type=oneshot
WorkingDirectory=/srv/www/sites/linux.montclaire.lan
ExecStart=/srv/www/sites/linux.montclaire.lan/make_index.sh
```

Is there a way to only allow domain init_t to access make_index.sh? By searching init_t I found this. Does this mean init_t can transition to these specific directories and file 'settings.php'?

$sesearch -T -s init_t -t httpd_sys_content_t
type_transition init_t httpd_sys_content_t:dir httpd_sys_rw_content_t "smarty";
type_transition init_t httpd_sys_content_t:dir httpd_sys_rw_content_t "upgrade";
type_transition init_t httpd_sys_content_t:dir httpd_sys_rw_content_t "uploads";
type_transition init_t httpd_sys_content_t:dir httpd_sys_rw_content_t "wp-content";
type_transition init_t httpd_sys_content_t:file httpd_sys_rw_content_t "settings.php";